# Interactive map plotly from shapefile

Tags: r, plotly, shapefile, r-sf

I would like to create an interactive map, using the plotly package in R.
However, I face the issue now that my geodata is contained in a shx shapefile, which the `plot_ly()` function seems to have issues with, as it does not contain long and lat but the known geometry lists. How do I solve this issue?

Here a selection of the geodata that I read in using the `st_read()` function:

```
 structure(list(mun_id = 1, geometry = structure(list(structure(list(
    structure(c(2680604.962, 2680570.93, 2680546.48, 2680527.546, 
    2680510.696, 2680475.176, 2680438.55, 2680419.956, 2680402.976, 
    2680401.001, 2680403.759, 2680394.18, 2680394.198, 2680397.223, 
    2680409.448, 2680420.546, 2680584.215, 2680601.274, 2680582.464, 
    2680570.35, 2680563.675, 2680564.359, 2680563.087, 2680554.433, 
    2680547.215, 2680537.773, 2680517.273, 2680503.011, 2680497.39, 
    2680494.454, 2680490.761, 2680485.479, 2680485.692, 2680488.398, 
    2680499.302, 2680492.059, 2680482.144, 2680473.227, 2680462.278, 
    2680455.456, 2680445.046, 2680434.409, 2680410.975, 2680401.454, 
    2680391.141, 2680380.1, 2680358.844, 2680333.986, 2680324.375, 
    2680314.134, 2680306.394, 2680298.573, 2680262.984, 2680239.015, 
    2680214.995, 2680188.918, 2680177.336, 2680162.854, 2680148.802, 
    2680112.306, 2680103.188, 2680093.781, 2680087.144, 2680080.896, 
    2680046.376, 2680033.146, 2680018.796, 2680007.668, 2679995.177, 
    2679969.759, 2679956.435, 2679942.832, 2679927.139, 2679832.957, 
    2679783.446, 2679773.215, 2679752.005, 2679744.955, 2679731.374, 
    2679705.994, 2679682.602, 2679658.233, 2679643.723, 2679629.883, 
    2679614.341, 2679592.331, 2679572.421, 2679556.94, 2679527.52, 
    2679498.829, 2679480.949, 2679473.258, 2679442.524, 2679437.945, 
    2679433.363, 2679427.146, 2679421.884, 2679403.806, 2679391.035, 
    2679381.045, 2679367.895, 2679356.655, 2679351.385, 2679334.305, 
    2679339.914, 2679341.974, 2679299.512, 2679274.593, 2679254.491, 
    2679247.271, 2679219.399, 2679223.2, 2679184.407, 2679183.247, 
    2679195.017, 2679201.927, 2679209.778, 2679220.017, 2679233.617, 
    2679242.247, 2679243.617, 2679231.849, 2679220.23, 2679209.859, 
    2679197.212, 2679191.08, 2679183.264, 2679175.355, 2679175.455, 
    2679180.075, 2679180.488, 2679176.725, 2679166.545, 2679136.245, 
    2679128.409, 2679117.939, 2679110.154, 2679107.809, 2679105.379, 
    2679085.444, 2679058.349, 2679049.939, 2679040.164, 2679019.259, 
    2679007.137, 2678996.153, 2678984.188, 2678960.422, 2678943.753, 
    2678925.343, 2678905.372, 2678875.591, 2678862.081, 2678852.886, 
    2678841.281, 2678828.156, 2678817.026, 2678807.476, 2678796.121, 
    2678769.911, 2678749.02, 2678740.25, 2678725.37, 2678700.795, 
    2678681.635, 2678671.625, 2678629.999, 2678609.309, 2678595.934, 
    2678583.679, 2678571.594, 2678563.959, 2678548.009, 2678499.012, 
    2678472.587, 2678452.398, 2678436.346, 2678414.501, 2678403.226, 
    2678399.986, 2678389.776, 2678371.926, 2678319.885, 2678311.345, 
    2678310.77, 2678316.135, 2678317.979, 2678318.665, 2678318.755, 
    2678305.375, 2678289.61, 2678277.67, 2678268.02, 2678254.475, 
    2678243.459, 2678242.254, 2678238.074, 2678260.965, 2678343.655, 
    2678347.385, 2678422.151, 2678426.486, 2678428.736, 2678440.736, 
    2678418.966, 2678408.325, 2678400.595, 2678431.995, 2678453.455, 
    2678450.544, 2678460.49, 2678462.546, 2678468.086, 2678474.422, 
    2678494.1, 2678498.337, 2678477.253, 2678471.951, 2678457.561, 
    2678459.469, 2678453.304, 2678446.613, 2678444.913, 2678444.003, 
    2678444.372, 2678436.703, 2678428.573, 2678426.142, 2678422.672, 
    2678422.442, 2678419.501, 2678419.591, 2678416.131, 2678414.731, 
    2678426.401, 2678439.851, 2678466.421, 2678479.271, 2678484.571, 
    2678482.78, 2678473.06, 2678475.7, 2678512.155, 2678517.58, 
    2678533.56, 2678547.73, 2678538.17, 2678560.659, 2678546.859, 
    2678532.19, 2678511.309, 2678485.297, 2678474.082, 2678469.828, 
    2678473.534, 2678467.514, 2678462.619, 2678455.849, 2678450.899, 
    2678439.64, 2678432.865, 2678395.225, 2678393.337, 2678392.669, 
    2678393.323, 2678396.099, 2678396.69, 2678396.58, 2678395.336, 
    2678362.508, 2678340.474, 2678333.174, 2678324.091, 2678303.011, 
    2678281.281, 2678251.461, 2678231.461, 2678206.911, 2678206.411, 
    2678204.471, 2678204.631, 2678232.13, 2678223.21, 2678222.791, 
    2678222.165, 2678218.18, 2678219.991, 2678230.111, 2678232.331, 
    2678233.091, 2678232.721, 2678230.661, 2678200.653, 2678200.081, 
    2678200.329, 2678201.48, 2678203.514, 2678206.355, 2678209.87, 
    2678213.142, 2678285.153, 2678294.233, 2678299.313, 2678299.962, 
    2678269.194, 2678264.294, 2678253.844, 2678245.324, 2678252.561, 
    2678260.87, 2678268.371, 2678276.9, 2678284.538, 2678292.185, 
    2678299.806, 2678308.301, 2678323.084, 2678429.405, 2678444.285, 
    2678458.516, 2678474.78, 2678489.97, 2678551.407, 2678550.948, 
    2678557.308, 2678549.079, 2678543.754, 2678508.858, 2678507.128, 
    2678466.979, 2678452.349, 2678250.185, 2678240.65, 2678231.426, 
    2678222.745, 2678122.995, 2678110.695, 2678124.805, 2678140.845, 
    2678187.096, 2678190.886, 2678190.506, 2678187.846, 2678188.246, 
    2678191.837, 2678197.168, 2678204.867, 2678229.698, 2678239.079, 
    2678244.657, 2678247.657, 2678248.799, 2678247.883, 2678256.009, 
    2678376.539, 2678398.919, 2678411.129, 2678425.949, 2678531.65, 
    2678583.921, 2678576.571, 2678572.381, 2678570.549, 2678604.012, 
    2678647.554, 2678653.483, 2678672.545, 2678723.046, 2678770.686, 
    2678816.567, 2678821.009, 2678865.556, 2678886.859, 2678922.216, 
    2678922.765, 2678924.805, 2678932.082, 2678944.806, 2679058.081, 
    2679074.471, 2679076.081, 2679082.53, 2679090.891, 2679157.71, 
    2679164.191, 2679169.449, 2679174.23, 2679177.04, 2679178.04, 
    2679179.567, 2679179.488, 2679191.566, 2679326.108, 2679352.278, 
    2679381.573, 2679403.258, 2679406, 2679432.688, 2679454.98, 
    2679508.866, 2679521.933, 2679548.336, 2679555.155, 2679565.77, 
    2679675.761, 2679728.529, 2679749.126, 2679765.488, 2679769.269, 
    2679748.97, 2679744.549, 2679757.718, 2679825.683, 2679833.602, 
    2679842.295, 2679850.856, 2679857.63, 2679862.78, 2679867.931, 
    2679890.429, 2679896.944, 2679903.169, 2679911.992, 2679920.547, 
    2679929.365, 2679938.345, 2679939.055, 2679938.071, 2679938.766, 
    2679934.02, 2679935.645, 2679953.716, 2679976.565, 2679979.864, 
    2679987.323, 2679990.438, 2679991.543, 2679993.426, 2679991.892, 
    2679993.046, 2679995.314, 2679997.284, 2679999.131, 2680007.295, 
    2680008.755, 2680024.874, 2680038.247, 2680050.064, 2680061.955, 
    2680068.471, 2680072.485, 2680075.767, 2680088.099, 2680090.988, 
    2680102.091, 2680126.901, 2680157.25, 2680181.308, 2680183.29, 
    2680180.971, 2680178.24, 2680175.141, 2680172.036, 2680168.741, 
    2680164.883, 2680168.505, 2680234.965, 2680256.797, 2680276.559, 
    2680297.53, 2680318.108, 2680347.596, 2680372.536, 2680400.574, 
    2680476.695, 2680500.774, 2680533.96, 2680540.256, 2680569.086, 
    2680601.916, 2680655.983, 2680675.438, 2680745.574, 2680792.718, 
    2680806.098, 2680946.456, 2680992.656, 2681014.786, 2681024.186, 
    2681049.826, 2681070.676, 2681076.796, 2681090.086, 2681116.386, 
    2681154.916, 2681145.876, 2681140.476, 2681132.336, 2681136.426, 
    2681137.736, 2681139.606, 2681134.906, 2681132.729, 2681095.828, 
    2681066.386, 2681077.736, 2681073.595, 2681093.465, 2681121.255, 
    2681135.335, 2681127.965, 2681108.285, 2681103.495, 2681091.135, 
    2681089.245, 2681067.595, 2681043.415, 2681023.875, 2681007.865, 
    2680984.175, 2680962.515, 2680945.185, 2680927.585, 2680927.265, 
    2680959.665, 2681006.125, 2681030.975, 2681050.025, 2681048.185, 
    2681039.204, 2681029.294, 2681035.584, 2681024.284, 2681007.914, 
    2680990.306, 2680987.854, 2680973.954, 2680955.524, 2680932.444, 
    2680921.455, 2680896.108, 2680868.788, 2680812.944, 2680786.128, 
    2680759.973, 2680728.122, 2680703.641, 2680697.913, 2680627.442, 
    2680604.962, 1236344.185, 1236364.095, 1236373.734, 1236374.727, 
    1236367.165, 1236346.372, 1236321.277, 1236309.779, 1236308.789, 
    1236308.38, 1236293.44, 1236272.615, 1236253.056, 1236237.611, 
    1236217.157, 1236207.315, 1235439.016, 1235427.88, 1235401.546, 
    1235378.698, 1235354.915, 1235338.422, 1235323.497, 1235301.648, 
    1235291.585, 1235282.045, 1235264.091, 1235246.299, 1235224.265, 
    1235189.155, 1235157.363, 1235127.254, 1235082.665, 1235068.874, 
    1235041.598, 1235035.207, 1235041.46, 1235046.421, 1235051.782, 
    1235054.538, 1235058.21, 1235061.331, 1235066.294, 1235032.636, 
    1235035.63, 1235028.791, 1235015.649, 1234997.744, 1234993.032, 
    1234989.968, 1234988.815, 1234988.602, 1234992.239, 1234993.067, 
    1234992.777, 1234990.639, 1234989.039, 1234985.644, 1234980.766, 
    1234963.804, 1234958.54, 1234951.95, 1234946.459, 1234940.525, 
    1234902.858, 1234890.128, 1234878.767, 1234871.247, 1234865.448, 
    1234857.293, 1234854.145, 1234852.404, 1234852.17, 1234857.538, 
    1234863.386, 1234841.108, 1234843.646, 1234842.496, 1234838.366, 
    1234838.476, 1234848.676, 1234868.516, 1234881.426, 1234889.896, 
    1234896.255, 1234909.955, 1234918.895, 1234921.145, 1234919.525, 
    1234913.775, 1234907.135, 1234871.085, 1234864.154, 1234863.742, 
    1234864.099, 1234865.88, 1234868.796, 1234882.455, 1234894.394, 
    1234906.984, 1234926.704, 1234941.184, 1234949.964, 1234939.844, 
    1234897.334, 1234867.744, 1234869.474, 1234873.664, 1234881.444, 
    1234850.944, 1234786.004, 1234783.684, 1234704.715, 1234700.315, 
    1234683.905, 1234677.695, 1234673.775, 1234673.385, 1234675.685, 
    1234657.715, 1234629.596, 1234628.017, 1234625.579, 1234622.63, 
    1234618.247, 1234616.637, 1234615.33, 1234614.815, 1234606.805, 
    1234602.895, 1234590.721, 1234588.916, 1234586.161, 1234564.92, 
    1234561.04, 1234562.33, 1234572.9, 1234591.83, 1234593.205, 
    1234612.555, 1234615.36, 1234622.584, 1234633.109, 1234639.079, 
    1234647.759, 1234665.414, 1234674.674, 1234690.043, 1234698.497, 
    1234703.968, 1234707.938, 1234709.223, 1234713.543, 1234721.206, 
    1234738.156, 1234750.941, 1234756.066, 1234754.731, 1234756.456, 
    1234783.255, 1234808.56, 1234824.125, 1234836.65, 1234848.245, 
    1234865.279, 1234870.119, 1234876.044, 1234877.899, 1234883.754, 
    1234897.657, 1234900.994, 1234899.939, 1234900.899, 1234878.578, 
    1234891.777, 1234896.934, 1234898.194, 1234905.104, 1234912.084, 
    1234911.604, 1234918.604, 1234936.029, 1234988.724, 1235001.744, 
    1235023.929, 1235038.109, 1235044.054, 1235053.289, 1235064.164, 
    1235124.375, 1235135.135, 1235144.37, 1235156.56, 1235167.94, 
    1235200.48, 1235218.39, 1235234.79, 1235245.43, 1235275.51, 
    1235278.1, 1235339.461, 1235343.66, 1235348.39, 1235358.22, 
    1235398.11, 1235421.34, 1235445.595, 1235470.92, 1235480.379, 
    1235494.859, 1235503.782, 1235506.622, 1235502.968, 1235504, 
    1235524.879, 1235534.43, 1235538.036, 1235550.981, 1235564.546, 
    1235566.602, 1235571.539, 1235580.949, 1235584.509, 1235591.799, 
    1235595.989, 1235604.739, 1235618.579, 1235621.099, 1235642.369, 
    1235648.039, 1235671.819, 1235675.549, 1235695.648, 1235700.938, 
    1235698.277, 1235702.558, 1235716.598, 1235727.427, 1235742.858, 
    1235757.907, 1235781.488, 1235788.196, 1235769.294, 1235776.616, 
    1235781.666, 1235798.596, 1235824.836, 1235856.185, 1235873.015, 
    1235889.793, 1235911.265, 1235948.325, 1235968.04, 1235993.265, 
    1236004.664, 1236008.863, 1236014.114, 1236025.894, 1236038.543, 
    1236076.837, 1236095.363, 1236180.445, 1236187.666, 1236195.651, 
    1236203.049, 1236215, 1236219.302, 1236225.571, 1236231.723, 
    1236310.069, 1236363.843, 1236388.01, 1236422.305, 1236420.655, 
    1236421.416, 1236417.626, 1236417.806, 1236418.936, 1236455.628, 
    1236482.488, 1236517.468, 1236590.848, 1236639.358, 1236651.344, 
    1236715.141, 1236787.758, 1236807.227, 1236848.008, 1236865.637, 
    1236884.767, 1236898.348, 1236907.769, 1237013.229, 1237017.254, 
    1237021.718, 1237026.038, 1237030.073, 1237033.621, 1237036.504, 
    1237038.279, 1237069.957, 1237077.648, 1237087.688, 1237099.317, 
    1237268.039, 1237276.529, 1237280.299, 1237286.97, 1237289.375, 
    1237291.531, 1237292.95, 1237293.959, 1237294.319, 1237294.175, 
    1237293.536, 1237292.251, 1237288.466, 1237252.901, 1237249.372, 
    1237247.608, 1237247.474, 1237249.13, 1237260.497, 1237263.098, 
    1237264.348, 1237308.539, 1237311.9, 1237291.648, 1237294.648, 
    1237480.79, 1237479.141, 1237491.3, 1237492.637, 1237495.48, 
    1237499.766, 1237562.503, 1237559.992, 1237571.973, 1237588.313, 
    1237647.611, 1237658.561, 1237670.241, 1237697.171, 1237716.421, 
    1237734.271, 1237747.761, 1237759.861, 1237786.77, 1237802.867, 
    1237819.39, 1237837.23, 1237856.16, 1237890.686, 1237890.19, 
    1237920.169, 1237925.309, 1237923.029, 1237912.239, 1238000.738, 
    1238031.777, 1238052.546, 1238071.646, 1238076.08, 1238088.302, 
    1238097.988, 1238067.006, 1238037.242, 1238060.896, 1238058.355, 
    1238034.289, 1238032.884, 1238032.57, 1238050.239, 1238080.551, 
    1238068.494, 1238056.49, 1238023.291, 1238027.299, 1238102.867, 
    1238108.616, 1238119.344, 1238149.954, 1238180.12, 1238393.265, 
    1238415.688, 1238436.122, 1238459.117, 1238477.841, 1238487.253, 
    1238512.451, 1238543.665, 1238541.86, 1238498.004, 1238498.859, 
    1238507.559, 1238491.1, 1238512.009, 1238501.86, 1238477.279, 
    1238444.639, 1238417.366, 1238400.642, 1238388.755, 1238393.475, 
    1238381.075, 1238370.781, 1238365.274, 1238358.418, 1238426.442, 
    1238449.479, 1238470.356, 1238486.399, 1238378.067, 1238379.813, 
    1238380.32, 1238379.418, 1238377.459, 1238375.035, 1238371.726, 
    1238351.825, 1238347.071, 1238343.339, 1238339.18, 1238336.25, 
    1238334.244, 1238333.183, 1238315.267, 1238310.813, 1238307.945, 
    1238297.235, 1238287.399, 1238261.055, 1238246.544, 1238241.664, 
    1238234.231, 1238226.517, 1238222.585, 1238220.391, 1238216.585, 
    1238202.351, 1238194.496, 1238182.721, 1238175.101, 1238166.085, 
    1238167.336, 1238147.421, 1238132.086, 1238128.265, 1238119.68, 
    1238111.24, 1238107.016, 1238099.82, 1238081.66, 1238076.203, 
    1238069.014, 1238062.981, 1238046.462, 1238030.37, 1238028.01, 
    1238025.006, 1238022.372, 1238020.155, 1238018.536, 1238017.349, 
    1238016.556, 1238007.419, 1237992.302, 1237982.027, 1237952.435, 
    1237931.087, 1237925.406, 1237918.581, 1237903.746, 1237850.994, 
    1237804.823, 1237787.913, 1237759.672, 1237736.15, 1237747.959, 
    1237769.281, 1237788.061, 1237788.054, 1237797.886, 1237777.865, 
    1237763.461, 1237626.733, 1237548.694, 1237521.824, 1237504.824, 
    1237493.394, 1237479.964, 1237462.384, 1237435.024, 1237441.654, 
    1237443.415, 1237395.275, 1237369.665, 1237352.065, 1237323.375, 
    1237280.635, 1237242.435, 1237220.845, 1237204.434, 1237173.262, 
    1237171.515, 1237148.295, 1237122.205, 1237101.195, 1237065.405, 
    1237052.985, 1237030.445, 1237001.945, 1236983.195, 1236963.085, 
    1236957.955, 1236951.535, 1236955.765, 1236942.515, 1236917.925, 
    1236914.455, 1236909.345, 1236890.195, 1236883.445, 1236868.015, 
    1236841.515, 1236811.905, 1236791.736, 1236769.006, 1236714.606, 
    1236686.496, 1236658.386, 1236647.876, 1236630.566, 1236592.256, 
    1236576.453, 1236573.166, 1236562.226, 1236506.776, 1236481.716, 
    1236476.159, 1236456.259, 1236442.846, 1236428.335, 1236417.239, 
    1236409.745, 1236409.425, 1236401.672, 1236343.515, 1236344.505, 
    1236344.185, 720.723, 718.27, 719.837, 716.867, 708.035, 
    686.725, 662.265, 650.235, 645.661, 645.351, 645.467, 645.048, 
    645.351, 645.098, 645.15, 645.439, 644.753, 648.768, 649.92, 
    651.145, 651.447, 651.092, 649.982, 649.27, 648.742, 647.976, 
    648.281, 650.194, 650.329, 648.5, 647.523, 647.327, 648.239, 
    649.375, 652.342, 652.813, 651.958, 651.492, 650.702, 650.47, 
    650.145, 649.961, 649.666, 646.227, 645.92, 644.363, 642.658, 
    641.443, 640.916, 640.166, 639.592, 638.988, 638.069, 637.813, 
    637.445, 637.428, 637.575, 637.756, 637.506, 637.065, 635.872, 
    634.82, 634.068, 633.531, 633.063, 633.659, 634.024, 634.122, 
    633.84, 633.511, 633.456, 633.424, 633.321, 636.758, 635.512, 
    631.395, 637.958, 639.092, 640.398, 640.441, 638.49, 638.74, 
    640.489, 642.356, 642.749, 644.682, 646.354, 645.992, 643.896, 
    638.958, 636.188, 624.559, 626.592, 626.813, 627.262, 628.003, 
    628.775, 630.628, 631.398, 631.898, 632.464, 632.93, 633.476, 
    628.363, 636.994, 635.769, 634.619, 634.114, 634.724, 625.178, 
    603.344, 603.193, 589.741, 589.416, 586.967, 585.438, 583.973, 
    582.128, 580.126, 571.095, 558.136, 557.725, 557.617, 557.31, 
    557.029, 556.894, 556.568, 556.337, 556.434, 556.128, 553.715, 
    553.646, 553.462, 553.204, 553.083, 552.902, 552.967, 552.334, 
    552.292, 552.111, 551.57, 551.374, 551.52, 550.986, 550.79, 
    550.77, 550.6, 550.136, 550.121, 549.715, 549.885, 549.32, 
    549.071, 548.738, 548.521, 548.469, 548.28, 548.042, 547.72, 
    546.819, 545.925, 545.622, 545.539, 544.804, 544.742, 544.568, 
    543.753, 543.678, 543.419, 543.179, 542.977, 542.755, 542.568, 
    541.396, 541.053, 540.824, 540.557, 540.158, 539.988, 539.775, 
    539.53, 539.033, 538.14, 537.969, 537.477, 536.895, 536.587, 
    536.489, 536.451, 535.467, 535.079, 534.271, 533.989, 533.814, 
    533.023, 532.717, 532.466, 535.747, 566.568, 567.165, 600.617, 
    601.475, 604.033, 612.476, 613.182, 612.663, 612.702, 629.607, 
    638.277, 638.165, 641.136, 641.366, 641.37, 641.113, 637.628, 
    637.125, 636.023, 635.518, 632.893, 632.708, 631.908, 631.747, 
    631.423, 630.119, 630.351, 629.372, 628.315, 628.033, 628.029, 
    627.485, 626.56, 626.18, 624.999, 625.001, 625.419, 626.205, 
    628.75, 630.06, 631.458, 632.117, 634.29, 635.305, 638.958, 
    640.042, 644.893, 651.572, 654.235, 666.143, 668.706, 670.557, 
    671.481, 670.223, 669.542, 668.736, 666.955, 666.887, 666.869, 
    666.788, 666.764, 666.658, 666.05, 664.755, 664.708, 664.759, 
    664.696, 664.5, 664.405, 664.271, 663.99, 662.959, 662.38, 
    662.029, 660.541, 657.232, 656.518, 653.999, 652.413, 649.6, 
    655.141, 654.083, 651.425, 658.71, 657.803, 657.488, 656.648, 
    659.663, 660.541, 660.3, 659.255, 658.012, 657.149, 656.831, 
    651.435, 651.504, 651.276, 651.35, 651.434, 651.524, 651.533, 
    651.523, 651.564, 651.152, 650.652, 650.363, 649.604, 648.952, 
    648.091, 648.102, 648.333, 648.629, 648.835, 648.979, 649.124, 
    649.21, 649.314, 649.417, 649.486, 652.818, 653.591, 654.405, 
    655.223, 656.004, 659.201, 659.292, 659.488, 661.595, 661.413, 
    659.637, 659.374, 658.965, 658.139, 646.579, 646.291, 645.97, 
    645.63, 641.708, 641.313, 642.13, 643.637, 651.934, 653.261, 
    654.705, 657.066, 659.398, 660.961, 662.481, 664.036, 665.894, 
    666.023, 666.474, 666.768, 666.557, 665.974, 666.856, 686.423, 
    690.411, 692.054, 693.66, 725.518, 732.833, 731.443, 732.042, 
    731.574, 707.962, 678.524, 682.008, 676.361, 646.95, 623.148, 
    612.36, 612.305, 604.592, 601.816, 596.934, 597.019, 597.085, 
    597.426, 597.357, 602.201, 603.255, 603.133, 602.458, 601.835, 
    594.836, 594.003, 593.352, 592.766, 592.488, 592.398, 592.242, 
    592.048, 592.615, 607.666, 610.481, 614.217, 622.394, 620.339, 
    625.069, 629.529, 635.908, 642.385, 646.887, 649.004, 648.996, 
    683.857, 723.94, 740.021, 750.742, 747.071, 742.095, 738.086, 
    738.313, 758.758, 758.686, 758.827, 758.91, 758.863, 758.949, 
    759.06, 760.148, 760.533, 760.727, 760.958, 761.383, 761.697, 
    762.204, 765.232, 766.181, 766.815, 768.223, 769.931, 775.985, 
    780.768, 781.434, 783.098, 784.965, 785.6, 786.1, 787.867, 
    790.215, 791.804, 792.262, 792.645, 794.766, 794.969, 797.678, 
    800.929, 803.893, 807.381, 809.193, 810.249, 812.319, 816.432, 
    817.146, 819.283, 824.667, 830.259, 834.786, 836.429, 836.419, 
    836.619, 836.68, 836.729, 836.714, 836.717, 837.352, 842.962, 
    844.872, 848.984, 851.931, 853.102, 854.88, 856.628, 862.048, 
    871.878, 874.055, 880.264, 884.852, 885.072, 882.355, 881.01, 
    882.637, 884.217, 885.413, 886.637, 882.424, 838.491, 837.48, 
    832.747, 827.916, 827.079, 823.447, 821.211, 831.75, 853.984, 
    858.982, 865.026, 869.95, 875.731, 871.394, 862.979, 857.712, 
    854.762, 841.705, 829.337, 829.357, 830.979, 822.738, 818.355, 
    821.652, 807.715, 808.148, 805.449, 803.579, 803.845, 792.217, 
    783.533, 782.488, 782.238, 782.024, 779.396, 780.815, 783.79, 
    783.304, 785.916, 778.011, 771.863, 776.747, 777.32, 775.001, 
    769.901, 776.262, 773.714, 765.024, 759.435, 759.404, 760.423, 
    773.669, 775.28, 774.981, 773.166, 771.22, 764.842, 760.583, 
    754.992, 746.251, 740.387, 733.012, 722.258, 720.723), dim = c(550L, 
    3L))), class = c("XYZ", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 2678110.695, 
ymin = 1234561.04, xmax = 2681154.916, ymax = 1238543.665), class = "bbox"), z_range = structure(c(zmin = 532.466, 
zmax = 886.637), class = "z_range"), crs = structure(list(input = "CH1903+ / LV95 + LN02 height", 
    wkt = "COMPOUNDCRS[\"CH1903+ / LV95 + LN02 height\",\n    PROJCRS[\"CH1903+ / LV95\",\n        BASEGEOGCRS[\"CH1903+\",\n            DATUM[\"CH1903+\",\n                ELLIPSOID[\"Bessel 1841\",6377397.155,299.1528128,\n                    LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n            PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",4150]],\n        CONVERSION[\"Swiss Oblique Mercator 1995\",\n            METHOD[\"Hotine Oblique Mercator (variant B)\",\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9815]],\n            PARAMETER[\"Latitude of projection centre\",46.9524055555556,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8811]],\n            PARAMETER[\"Longitude of projection centre\",7.43958333333333,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8812]],\n            PARAMETER[\"Azimuth of initial line\",90,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8813]],\n            PARAMETER[\"Angle from Rectified to Skew Grid\",90,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8814]],\n            PARAMETER[\"Scale factor on initial line\",1,\n                SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8815]],\n            PARAMETER[\"Easting at projection centre\",2600000,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8816]],\n            PARAMETER[\"Northing at projection centre\",1200000,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n                ID[\"EPSG\",8817]]],\n        CS[Cartesian,2],\n            AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n                ORDER[1],\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n            AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n                ORDER[2],\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        USAGE[\n            SCOPE[\"Cadastre, engineering survey, topographic mapping (large and medium scale).\"],\n            AREA[\"Liechtenstein; Switzerland.\"],\n            BBOX[45.82,5.96,47.81,10.49]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",2056]],\n    VERTCRS[\"LN02 height\",\n        VDATUM[\"Landesnivellement 1902\"],\n        CS[vertical,1],\n            AXIS[\"gravity-related height (H)\",up,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        USAGE[\n            SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n            AREA[\"Liechtenstein; Switzerland.\"],\n            BBOX[45.82,5.96,47.81,10.49]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",5728]]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 1L, class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(mun_id = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Comment: regarding shx, see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294868/explaining-difference-between-shx-and-shp-files-of-shapefile you are reading the shp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `plot_ly` or `plot_geo` for this. Or you can plot in `ggplot2` and then use `ggplotly` function.

Here's the plot for one polygon that you provided:

```
plot_ly(df)
```

[image]

```
plot_geo(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, my issue then seems to lie with adding the trace.